# Baking pose in Blender

Tags: export, rigging, bones, import

I have exported a model from DAZ, and I am fighting with the export options. 
I would like to bring in the bones.

When I import my fbx file, it looks like this in Blender:

[image]

When I click the "Pose" icon, the model looks as I expected.

[image]

However, when I then export the model from within Blender (with "Pose" activated), the model is still as weird as shown in the first image.

I would like to understand what is happening here. 
I guess it is about baking the pose, right?

If yes, do I have to bake the pose in DAZ or in Blender?